# Why this ERROR: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have postqs and users table. user_id is foreign key in postqs table . i have a form and after i submit the form all the data saving in database correctly. but it is not directing to index page its showing this ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `Postqs` (`question`, `description`,
>   `solution`, `image`, `tags`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hh,
>   bb, bb, images .bmp.jpg, bb, 2017-09-20 08:14:32, 2017-09-20
>   08:14:32))

How i can solve it?

store controller function :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'question' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required',

    ]);

    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->postqs()->create($request->all() );

    $input = $request->all();
    $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

    $postqs = Postqs::create($input);
    $postqs->tag($tags);

    return redirect()->route('postqs.index')
                    ->with('success','Your question created successfully');
```

index controller function:

```
   $postqs=Postqs::whereHas('user')->get();        
    return view('postqs.index',compact('postqs','users'));
```

postqs model:

```
    protected $fillable = 
    ['question','description','solution','image','tags','user_id'];

    public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User"); }
```

User model:

```
    public function postqs(){
     return $this->hasMany("App\Postqs");
    }
```

Comment: The error means that your not passing a value to that field and as it has not been given some form of default value (`NULL` or whatever) the query is failing. If that is meant to be a auto incrementing field, ensure that it actually has been set as such. If you understand what the error means debugging it becomes very easy.

Comment: Try this `$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
Postqs::create($data);` !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the field user_id in your table is not nullable, and you tried to save post without user_id, or may be user_id is not passed by request.
Try this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'question' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'tags' => 'required',

]);

$user = auth()->user();
$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id']=$user->id;
$user->postqs()->create($data);
$tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

$postqs = Postqs::create($data);
//$postqs->tag($tags);
$postqs->tag()->save($tags);

return redirect()->route('postqs.index')
                ->with('success','Your question created successfully');
```

Comment: its showing this error now:
(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

Comment: try to logout and re-login, believe me, i faced this problem many times

Comment: still having  problem. General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: yes.it works. the error is solved. but in homepage the tag is not displaying. anything missing there?

Comment: is tag method in Postqs a relation or what? if it is a relation try this $postqs->tag()->save($tags);

Comment: edited the answer (again), how is it going? any changes?

Answer (score 1):

you did not post your table's schema, but from the error it seems that you have a field `user_id` which is set as non-null and does not have a default value- which means every insert query must provide its value.

The solution - either give the column a default value, or pass it in your query

Comment: but it save data and foriegn key in database. isit my store function in correct?

Answer (score 1):

When i had this error, this was my solution from @Matius's answer

```
$user = auth()->user();
$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id']=$user->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a user to your database? Please add a user and then you must add `user_id` to `$fillable`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after a Mysql update, the indexes of the database were gone. I was getting the same error messages that we are talking about.

I had to recreate the indexes and make the id column on each table the primary key, and auto-increment.

After that...  Everything, works.